# Exception handling trouble, why?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is my main:

```
int main() {
  Inventory Master;
  bool flag;
  Customer Bob("Bob", "CreditCard.txt");
  Customer Joe("Joe", "CreditCard.txt" );



  Master.firststock( "inventory.txt" );
  vector<Food> temp = Master._Inv;
  cout <<"Hi, What would you like to buy today?" << endl;
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++ ) {
    cout << temp[i].name << " " << temp[i].quant << " " << temp[i].price << endl;
  }

  cout <<"\n";
  Food Apple("Apples", .99, 10);
  Food Orange("Oranges", .99, 10);
  Food Chip("Chips", 3.00, 10);

  cout <<"\nHi Bob" << endl;
  flag = Bob.addCart(Apple, 7, &Master);
  cout <<"Bob's total purchases are Currently: \n";
  Bob.report();
  flag = Bob.addCart(Orange, 2, &Master);
  flag = Bob.addCart(Chip, 2, &Master);
  Bob.report();
  flag = Bob.removeCart();
   Bob.report();
  cout <<"Bob, ";
  flag = Bob.checkout(&Master);
```

here is the following i implemented to remove food from my vector _Cart:

```
bool Customer::removeCart() {
  bool flag;
  int q = 0;
  unsigned int i=0;
  string remove;

  cout << "\nWhat would you like to remove and how much would you like to remove?" << endl;
  cin >> remove >> q;
 for (i =0; i < _Cart.size(); i++) {
  if(remove == _Cart[i].name) {
      if (q >= 0) {
    _Cart[i].quant -= q;
    //inv->_Inv[i].quant += q;
    cout <<"\nYou removed " << q << " " << remove <<" In your cart\n" << endl;
    return true;
      }
      if  (q < 0) {
          cout << "Invalid number of " << remove << " being removed.\n" << endl;
          return true;
      }
  }
  else {      
  try {
    throw remove;
}

  catch (string param) {
    cout << "\n" << remove << " doesn't exist in your cart\n" << endl;
        }

        return true;
    }
 }
```

My header containing the the function removeCart:

```
class Customer {
  public:

   Customer(string n, string fileName);
    ~Customer() { _Cart.clear(); };
    bool addCart(Food f, int q, Inventory* inv);
    bool removeCart();
    void report(); 
    bool checkout(Inventory* inv); 
  protected:
    string remove;
    string name;
    int q;
    int card;
    double balance;
    CreditCard _CC(int card,double balance);
    vector<Food> _Cart;
};
```

Now for some reason when i call removeCart, entering "Apples" works but i noticed i made a food object called Apple so not sure why typing "Apples" works for being removed instead of "Apple". Also when i try "Orange" or "Chip" the exception is shown but as you can see in main i added Chip and Orange to Bob's Cart. I could appreciate the help.

Comment: Post the exception message and show the lines it occurs on. What happens when you input _'Apple'_?

Comment: when i input in the console  'Apple 3' i get the exception: Apple doesn't exist in your cart

Answer (score 0):

You are making an object called Apple containing a member of type std::string which holds characters "Apples". Only your compiler knows that you called an object Apple but your program compare string "Apples" with your input. Same with Orange and Chip.

Answer (score 0):

You've *declared* an **object** called `Apple` somewhere in your code.

You've then **instantiated** an instance of an `Apple` class and set the `Apple::name` member to `'Apples'`, a string.

You're not comparing the *input* with the *class name*, you're comparing the *input* with the **member data of the `Apple` class**.